# TensorFlow: How to load images asynchronously for streaming video predictions in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am training a model that takes a video as input and makes per-frame predictions (object tracking, to be specific).

TensorFlow provides the `data.Dataset.prefetch()` operation to load images asynchronously during training. This works well because my training sequences are only a few frames long. However, I would also like to load images asynchronously during testing, where the sequences can be thousands of frames long.

Is there any convenient way to achieve this in TensorFlow? I suppose I could define each video as a `Dataset` object? This seems kind of ugly because I need to create one operation in the graph for each video in my dataset?

Thank you!

Comment: from your description, is your testing set consist of images that could be a variable number of frames depending on the video?

Comment: Yes, each video in the testing set contains a different (and large) number of frames.

Comment: can you share more details regarding how your data is stored? Do you have like a folder for each video, which contains all the frames for that video, or do you have videos, which you take and you split in to frames and then feed to your model?

Comment: I have a directory for each video, containing an image file for each frame.

Comment: maybe you can create dataset objects for each video, [batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) them to length of your video, and use the [interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) method to interleave all the videos in to one single dataset? You can then prefetch one element at a time, which would correspond to all images of one video?